# How can I validate two columns at the same time and update one of the column values in cognos

Tags: cognos

I've requirement to validate two column values and update one of the column values only if both the column value condition saitisfies. To be precise, if column B has value 'system' and column A has blank value then I should update column A value as 'NA'. Can I achieve this Cognos and the values should get displayed in report as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Data Item [A] Expression**

```
CASE  
WHEN [B] = 'system' AND [A] is missing THEN 'NA' 
ELSE [A]
END
```

For this to work, A has to be a string type.